# Unit testing void controller and service methods

Tags: java, maven, junit, rest

I have built a REST API that does basic CRUD operations on a product database and I am now unit testing all the methods within the controller and service layer. I have realised that methods such as addProduct, updateProduct or deleteProduct return void on both of the layers.

How do I go about mocking the repository when testing the service layer and mocking the service while testing controller layer for these methods?

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST,value ="/products")
public void addProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
    productService.addProduct(product);
}
```

Service method:

```
public void addProduct(Product product){
    productRepository.save(product);
}
```

I have commented in the fields where I need help for the addProduct() methods.

Controller tests:

```
package com.product.controllers;

import com.product.entities.Product;
import com.product.services.ProductService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ProductControllerTest {

@InjectMocks
ProductController productController;

@Mock
ProductService productService;

@Test
public void getHomePage(){
    String homePageText = "Welcome to the home page!";
    assertEquals(homePageText,productController.getHomePage());
}

@Test
public void getAllProducts(){
    
    Product product1 = new Product();
    product1.setId("001");
    product1.setName("TV");
    product1.setPrice(999.99);

    Product product2 = new Product();
    product2.setId("002");
    product2.setName("Mobile");
    product2.setPrice(300D);

    List<Product> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfProducts.add(product1);
    listOfProducts.add(product2);

    when(productService.getAllProducts()).thenReturn(listOfProducts);
    assertEquals(listOfProducts,productController.getAllProducts());
}

@Test
public void getProductById(){
    
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId("001");
    product.setName("TV");
    product.setPrice(999.99);

    when(productService.getProductById("001")).thenReturn(product);
    assertEquals(new ResponseEntity<Product> (product, HttpStatus.OK),productController.getProductById("001"));
}

@Test
public void addProduct() {
    
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId("001");
    product.setName("TV");
    product.setPrice(999.99);

    // need help with this
}
}
```

Service tests:

```
package com.product.services;

import com.product.entities.Product;
import com.product.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProductServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
ProductService productService;

@Mock
ProductRepository productRepository;

@Test
public void getAllProducts() {

    Product product1 = new Product();
    product1.setId("001");
    product1.setName("TV");
    product1.setPrice(999.99);

    Product product2 = new Product();
    product2.setId("002");
    product2.setName("Mobile");
    product2.setPrice(300D);

    List<Product> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfProducts.add(product1);
    listOfProducts.add(product2);

    when(productRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(listOfProducts);
    assertEquals(listOfProducts, productService.getAllProducts());
}

@Test
public void getProductById() {

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId("001");
    product.setName("TV");
    product.setPrice(999.99);

    when(productRepository.findById("001")).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(product));
    assertEquals(product, productService.getProductById("001"));


}

@Test
public void addProduct() {

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId("001");
    product.setName("TV");
    product.setPrice(999.99);

    // need help with this
}
}
```

Comment: I would expect that a REST part has at least return code like 200 etc. but giving void does not really make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is quite simple so I'm not sure you need to unit test it. But if you want to, you can make use of your Mockito's mocks' `verify` method. For example when testing `addProduct` :

```
@InjectMocks
ProductService productService;

@Mock
ProductRepository productRepository;

// ...

@Test
public void testAddProduct() { 
   Product dummyProduct = new Product();

   productService.addProduct(dummyProduct);

   // eq() is from the Mockito matchers package
   Mockito.verify(productRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(eq(dummyProduct))
}
```

This verifies that `save` was called on time on the mocked repository with an argument of `dummyProduct`.

You also may want to check out Mockito "argument captors".

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking for! I know the code is simple but I am learning how to write unit tests for different methods so that is why I want to unit test all of them :)